# D3Graphviz cannot render DOT file that GVEdit can

Tags: d3.js, graphviz

I have a largish DOT file (3,800 lines) which renders ok using GVEdit (included in the Windows download of Graphviz) but when embedded in a D3-Graphviz page (which works OK with a simpler/smaller graph) the page fails to load. Using Chrome's 'inspect' window I see the error message :

> Uncaught syntax error in line 1 near 'subgraph' d3-graphviz.min.js:1

(Line 1 of the source isn't a subgraph statement)

Is there anyway to find out exactly what part of the source D3-Graphviz doesn't like?

Comment: Fixed the issue by starting with a minimal, working graph and slowly adding bits until it failed.Issue was with the script that build the DOT file with some minor syntax errors that GVEdit overlooks but D3-Graphviz doesn't Tedious to find so a quicker way would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the process I had to generate the graph had a bug, and was generating 'bad' DOT code. GVEDIT.exe - as distributed with GraphViz - dimply overlooked the errors but the DOT renderer in D3Graphviz (viz.js) wouldn't

(The error was actually some extraneous DOT lines being written to my output file after I had closed it, resulting in the closing '}' appearing about 150 lines from the end and I was also missing a '} } }' to close the final nested 3 subgraphs.

So from the code you could see what I meant to do, but viz.js would have it wheeres GVEDIT seems happy to overlook a '}' without a preceding '{' and also happy to get to the end of the file without the subgraph definitions being closed.